# TYPO3 - linked files not referenced in backend filelist

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

I have a problem with referenced files and images in the backend filelist. If i e.g. place an image on a page, this image is referenced in T3 BE filelist, so i can‘t delete this file in the filelist. Thats ok. But, if this image is linked to a local file maybe a .pdf or something, this pdf-file is not referenced in the filelist. So i can delete this file and there is no warning. It’s a 8.7. Installation. In T3 6.2 everything was ok. Anyone having an idea, how to fix this behaviour?

DB: sys_file_reference => FIELD:link = t3://file?uid=3

[Screen BE filelist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOIPE.jpg)
[Screen content element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGIDI.jpg)

Comment: I've tested this and it looks like this is a bug. It doesn't just happen with pdf files, but any type of file referenced in a link in a file reference. It works fine in TYPO3 7.6, but not in 8.7. I don't have a properly working TYPO3 9 installation, so I can't test it in that version. I can't find a bug report for it, so I don't think it's a known bug. Can you create a bug report for it on https://forge.typo3.org?

Comment: Thank you, Rudy, bug is reported.